# Decipher UIViewController property warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, warnings

I cant understand what this warning I get on Xcode is about. Searching for it on google wasn't of too much help. If anyone has come across this warning before, it'd be great if I could get some hints on how I'd be able to get rid of it.

The (updated) screenshot is at:

http://imagebin.antiyes.com/images/0116033001255720169_90.png

Thanks again.

**EDIT:**
warning messages, for future searching
`warning: property 'title' 'copy' attribute does not match super class 'UIViewController' property

warning: property 'title' type does not match super class 'UIViewController' property type`

Comment: you can upload a screenshot at http://imagebin.antiyes.com/ , that link does not work

Comment: That link isn't going to work out too well I think.

Comment: Better yet, transcribe it here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By naming the property "title" in `PageViewController`, you are actually overriding the `title` property defined in `UIViewController`. So either choose a different name for your subclass' property, or use the one defined by `UIViewController`. I would suggest the second one, since it looks like you are simply trying to store a the title of your view.

When you override a property in a subclass, there are certain attributes that cannot be different from the superclass' definition. Two of those things are type and copy vs. retain vs. assign (the "copy attribute", as the warning states). Since you've defined your version of `title` differently in this areas than `UIViewController`, you get the warnings.